# Как глобально отлавливать щелчок мыши?

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно чтобы с помощью winapi отлавливался щелчок мыши абсолютно везде,в любом окне.Я пишу но ничего не происходит:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(
_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
_In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
_In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
_In_ int nCmdShow)
{

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT 
message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Console allocation 
failed", L"Error Win32 Api", MB_OK | 
MB_ICONINFORMATION);

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: по коду не видно где у вас утанавливается хук, если это вообще происходит)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v%3Dvs.85)